# Possible alternate proof of Bertrand's postulate.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

I don't know if I am right. So I came here. What I did was use the theta function, defined as the sum $\theta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x} \log{p}$. So we have that there is always a prime between x and 2x, for x sufficiently large. Taking this function on both sides yields $\theta(x)$<$\theta(2x)$. What I did was this.
I wrote $\theta(x)$ in terms of the previous sum. So in particular, $\theta(x)=\sum_{p\leq 2x} \log{p}$=($\sum_{p\leq x} \log{p}$)+($\sum_{p<q\leq 2x} \log(q)$). So in particular, there is some $\log q$ > $\log p$, where the $\log(p)$ is "contained" in $\theta(x)$, and $\log(q)$ is "contained" in the larger sum, $\theta(2x)$. So we have that there exists a $\log q$ in between $\theta(x)$ and $\theta(2x)$. (Or more exactly, the logarithms in the sum). So we have there is a prime between x and 2x.

I know its worded badly, but I suppose would could say it is a motivation for a more formal version, for which I am still working on. But I hope it makes sense up to some degree.

Comment: I think there's a circular logic that goes here. You need to prove the existence of $q$ in the interval $(x, 2x]$ and you are actually using it to prove $\theta(x) <\theta(2x)$.

Comment: What I did was split the sum $\theta(2x)$ and showed there has to be some $\log q$ contained in the second part of the sum, so that there exists a $\log q$ "in between" $\theta(x)$ and $\theta(2x)$.

Comment: One could also prove by contradiction. If one assume that there does not exist a q such that $\log q$ > $\log p$, then we would obtain $\theta(2x)$=$\theta(x)$, which would be a contradiction for sufficiently large n.

Comment: You haven't proven that $\theta(2x) = \theta(x)$ would be a contradiction for large $n$ yet.

Comment: Well uhhhhhhh,... . Hmmmmmmm. Alright I will do that.